# Table used in proc defaults to the calling schema instead of dbo if the table exists in that schema too

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

1. I created `mytable` in both `dbo` and `schema1` schemas.
2. Then a proc using `mytable`. Notice schema name is not present.
3. Executing the proc used `schema1.mytable`. Shouldn't it have been `dbo.mytable` when schemaname is not present? What is the concept involved here?

   ```
   create proc schema1.myproc
   as
   begin

      select id into #tbl
      from mytable

      select * from #tbl

   end


   select * from dbo.mytable
   ++++++++
   id  name
   1   a
   ++++++++

   select * from schema1.mytable
   ++++++++
   id  name
   2   b
   ++++++++


   exec schema1.myproc
   ++++++++
   id
   2
   ++++++++
   ```

Comment: Please pardon the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Since your stored procedure schema is `schema1` if you don't mention the schema name it will be used

change your sp to this it will return the dbo data

```
create proc dbo.myproc
as
begin

   select id into #tbl
   from mytable

   select * from #tbl

end
```

Comment: Thanks @Reza for the formatting and reply to the post. I tested this bit on my own and saw the results.This would mean if i am creating procs with other schemas, definitely i need to provide full names of tables being used that may exist in both the schemas.  Can you please direct me to some online article regarding this?

Comment: @Suyash I couldn't find any references but I knew it from my experience ;)

Comment: see this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/47KTHctUjzM